# TCP socket fails to (reliably) deliver what is sent after a restart of application

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I basically create a socket, perform a couple of Sends, Shutdown the socket and Dispose it. This is repeated for the duration of the application session as data is being queued to be sent.

This works without issue until I restart the receiving application. Then I find at the receiving end that the last byte array I send in this sequence is not always received. The receiver knows it should get an End marker at some point, telling it this is it, so it can close the receive socket. I found after an application restart the End marker does not get delivered reliably. The receiver then continues to wait for it, it keeps calling BeginReceive and getting zero bytes. This results in a high CPU load and the receive socket not being closed.

Restarting the receiving application does not fix it, a reboot of the machine however does. Also, restarting all application and using different port numbers fixes it.

I can mitigate this by trying to receive three times with a short wait and giving up if nothing more comes in, assuming it is not going to happen anymore and this is indeed the end even if no explicit End marker was received. But I want to understand what is happening.

The experience suggests it has something to do with Windows recycling sockets under the hood.

Is there something I can do to get a "clean" socket other than using a different port number? Can anyone explain what is happening?

This is the crux of the sending code of which the End constant (which is just 5 fixed bytes) does not always make it to the receiver:

```
using (socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
{
    socket.SendBufferSize = 0x10000;  // increase send buffer size from default 8K to 64K
    socket.Connect(this.Host, this.Port);

    bool oneOrMoreSent = false;

    while (this.queue.TryDequeue(out IMessage? msg))
    {
        if (msg != null)
        {
            byte[] packet = (msg as Message).Packet ??= CreatePacket(msg);
            _ = socket.Send(packet);
            oneOrMoreSent = true;
        }
    }

    if (oneOrMoreSent)
    {
        _ = socket.Send(End);
    }

    socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
}
```

[Edit]

The article about half closed connections pointed to by JonasH was helpful and confirmed the statement of the other commenter with the ridiculous name. The application I implemented the sending code in is not the most well behaved regarding shutdown logic and we do use kill commands to make it go away when needed so this would explain the emergence of half closed connections where the receiver waits for more data that should come but never does. It is still weird that restarting the receiving application apparently does not release/cleanup the receiving socket.

Understanding this a little better, I settled for a straightforward fix. If the receiver expects more data but repeatedly doesn't get it, waiting 1 ms in between BeginReceive calls, it will now accept that the sending end is dead and return from the handler. So the receiving logic will never stubbornly wait for data, thus locking up the socket forever. This safeguard should have been there in the first place and it fixes my problem.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: You might want to read Stephen clearys article about [tcp](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html), especially the section about dropped connections.

Comment: `BeginReceive and getting zero bytes` is an indication that the other side has closed the connection. This side should close its socket and - if it's the server - listen for a new connection, otherwise open a client connection to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I improved my receiving logic with it and my problem is gone.